# Neo4j: How Do I Add COMMENTS to a *.cql (cypher) File?

Tags: file, neo4j, format, cypher, cql

The format of the Cypher query language in script files still appears a bit ambiguous...how do i add comments to such a file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You use double slashes for cypher comments

`// this is a comment`

the file format is of Neo4j-shell not so much of Cypher.

Use semicolons to end statements and you can surround a number of statements with `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` for a larger transaction.

You can also have other neo4j-shell commands in that file. Like `schema --await`

Comment: By "neo4j-she'll" I assume you mean *.sh...?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the implementation of // for comments seems buggy...

I ran this test.cql script ...

// Creates this node
`CREATE  (rec:Customer {Name:"CUSTOMER1"});`
// Creates this node 
`CREATE  (rec:Customer {Name:"CUSTOMER2"});`

`CREATE  (rec:Customer {Name:"CUSTOMER3"});`    // DOES NOT create this node (bug?)
`CREATE  (rec:Customer {Name:"CUSTOMER4"});`    // DOES NOT create this node (bug?)

// DOES NOT create this node (bug?)
`CREATE  (rec:Customer {Name:"CUSTOMER5"});`

// Creates this node
`CREATE  (rec:Customer {Name:"CUSTOMER6"});`

*i.e. Only nodes CUSTOMER1, CUSTOMER2 and CUSTOMER6 were created when I ran this via neo4-shell (Ubuntu 16.04)*

Comment: I would concur with this point, especially when you start interspersing directives like ":param" with comments.  I'm filing a bug with neo4j.

Comment: I too concur. Blank comment lines also seem to cause the command on the next line to be ignored